# Python3.8 socketpair failed (s.o. cygwin)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cygwin, python-2.6, python-sockets

Under cygwin console:

````
$ python3.8

Python 3.8.7 (default, Jan 26 2021, 07:37:32)

[GCC 10.2.0] on cygwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```>>> import socket as s```

```>>> s.socketpair()```
 
 File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 571, in socketpair

    ```a, b = _socket.socketpair(family, type, proto)```

SystemError: <built-in function socketpair> returned NULL without setting an error
````

but...

````
$ python2.7

Python 2.7.18 (default, Jan  2 2021, 09:22:32)

[GCC 10.2.0] on cygwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```>>> import socket as s```

```>>> s.socketpair()```

(<socket object, fd=3, family=1, type=1, protocol=0>, <socket object, fd=4, family=1, type=1, 
protocol=0>)
````

**I don't know where to look! :((**

THX

Comment: not your fault. It is a current bug in the python/cygwin package

Comment: I resolved it with a little change in socket.py line 571:

#if hasattr(_socket, "socketpair"):  <---That's original but doesn't works.

if not hasattr(_socket, "socketpair"): <--- That's works!

Comment: interesting workaround, it bypasses the system call and use it own build

Comment: Thanks for the idea. https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2021-January/247679.html

Answer (score 0):

The new versions implement a workaround similar to your idea

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin/2021-February/247684.html

Comment: The main reason for my question was that I had an error when launching jupyter under cygwin command window. Now everything works fine with python3.8 and I use python osgeo/gdal as well.